# Chrome DevTools "isSystemKey" Debugger Attribute

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-devtools, keyevent

While looking into `chrome.debugger.sendCommand` documentation, I came across an attribute, [isSystemKey](https://chromedevtools.github.io/devtools-protocol/tot/Input/#:%7E:text=isSystemKey). I wonder whether this could be used to verify whether a key is typed by a human or program (similar to the `isTrusted` event attribute), but there doesn't appear to be any documentation on it, in the linked URL or elsewhere. Not a mention of its usage, as far as I can see.

So what does this boolean attribute do?

Some example code to illustrate, given a character `c`, a tab id `tab_id` and the debugger currently attached to that same tab:

```js
let options = {
    'key': c,
    'type': 'keyDown',
    'nativeVirtualKeyCode': c.charCodeAt(),
    'windowsVirtualKeyCode': c.charCodeAt(),
    'macVirtualKeyCode': c.charCodeAt(),
    'isSystemKey': true // What does this change, compared to its falsy default?
}
// Pressing key
chrome.debugger.sendCommand({tabId: tab_id}, "Input.dispatchKeyEvent", options, () => {
    // Releasing key
    options.type = 'keyUp';
    chrome.debugger.sendCommand({tabId: tab_id}, "Input.dispatchKeyEvent", options, () => {
        // Detaching debugger
        chrome.debugger.detach({tabId: tab_id});
    });
});
```

Comment: I'm fairly certain that this is a reference to the platform-independent [super/meta key](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Super_key_(keyboard_button)) and corresponds to [KeyboardEvent.metaKey](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/metaKey).

Comment: It means that a key like Alt can be handled by the OS, see the comments [in the source code](https://source.chromium.org/search?q=isSystemKey%20-file:test%20-file:%5B%2F-%5DDebug%2F%20lang:cpp).